# problem IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python

i have some problem, when i run `py -tt first_ai.py` a message like this appear :

```
File "first_ai.py", line 41
    NN = Neural_Network()
                        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

my part of  code is :

```
NN = Neural_Network()

   o = NN.forward(X)

   print("Sorti predit par l'IA : \n" + str(o))
   print("Vrai sorti : \n" str(y))
```

Comment: So fix the indentation?

Comment: Indentation issues usually can be traced in a IDE. Can you provide a full code before the problem line?

Comment: @StacyGordeeva The indentation error is clearly visible even in the code here on SO

Comment: There is no need for the indentation you have made from  line 2...Why on earth  have you indented it? There is no if...else or loop etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why is the source code after `NN = Neural_Network()` indented? There is no reason to do this.

```
NN = Neural_Network()

o = NN.forward(X)

print("Sorti predit par l'IA : \n" + str(o))
print("Vrai sorti : \n" str(y))
```